# Are there any minhagim which people do on shavous night as a substitute for staying up all night?

Tags: minhag, shavuos

Are there any minhagim which people do on shavous night as a substitute for staying up all night? I just want to know if this type of minhag exists or existed.

Comment: What do you mean by a substitute? Eat lots of dairy instead of staying up? I'm not sure why you think such a minhag would exist.

Comment: Staying up all night is a minhag already. It's not a requirement. When you are up all night learning Torah, you gain the mitzvah of learning Torah, which, BTW, you should be doing, ideally, each moment of the  day and night, if you physically could. I assume you also know that Torah learning is equal to accomplishing all other mitzvot. So, seriously - Is there any possible equal substitute for this?

Comment: To the three people who voted to close this question as "unclear what you're asking": it'd I think help the asker clarify the question if you'd comment nicely regarding what's unclear about it. (Fwiw I don't see anything unclear about it after my recent edit.)

Comment: Get a good night's sleep, then learn lots of Torah in the day!

Comment: @msh210 You're either up or sleeping / dozing. It's a dichotomy. So, if there is a minhag to be up, how could NOT being up substitute for that? Am I missing some aspect, here? This comment is in addition to my previous one, namely what can one possibly substitute for the mitzvah of Torah learning, which, is usually listed as the top mitzvah, possible, that nothing else can surpass in importance?

Comment: @DanF I think the point of the question is whether there was a minhag specifically NOT to stay up at night but rather to do "X" - get up early, daven early, and learn all day, for example.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky An answer was posted meanwhile. However, somewhat in line with the last sentence in the answer, a number of rabbanim in my previously lived neighborhood made a specific point to study only for a few hours (11 PM - about 2 or 3 AM) and they told everyone to sleep for a few hours and then come back for Shacharit at the "normal" 9 AM. The reason is that they saw no purpose in having tired people daven and doze off in the middle, esp. when the Shat"z was doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I saw it brought down in the שפתי חן on shavuos that some Rebbes make a tish on the first night in lieu of saying the tikkun leil shavuos because  תערוך לפני שלחן  has the same roshei teivos as תיקון ליל שבועות

Edit: it's seems that according to that minhag they stay up until just after chatzos and then go to sleep. This is considered their tikkun. It's my understanding that this is because our generation is considered too weak to stay up all night and do the full tikkun properly.